# In Matlab axis, how to update only the data while keeping all the axis properties?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I need to create a movie. Suppose, I create an axis and plot on it something very customized:

```
figure;
ax = plot(x, y, 'linewidth', 3, 'prop1', value1, 'prop2', value2, ...);
grid minor;
axis(ax, [xmin xmax ymin ymax]);
legend(ax, ...);
xlabel(ax, ...);
ylabel(ax, ...);
title(ax, ...);
```

Now I run a loop, where only the values of `y` are being updated.

```
for k = 1 : N
% y changes, update the axis
end
```

What is the fastest and easiest way to update the axis with new `y` (or `x` and `y`), keeping all the axis properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fast way is to simply update the y-values of the data you've plotted:

```
%# note: plot returns the handle to the line, not the axes
%# ax = gca returns the handle to the axes
lineHandle = plot(x, y, 'linewidth', 3, 'prop1', value1, 'prop2', value2, ...);

%# in the loop
set(lineHandle,'ydata',newYdata)
```

**EDIT** What if there are multiple lines, i.e. `lineHandle` is a vector? You can still update in one step; you need to convert the data to a cell array, though.

```
%# make a plot with random data
lineHandle = plot(rand(12));

%# create new data
newYdata = randn(12);
newYcell = mat2cell(newYdata,12,ones(1,12));

%# set new y-data. Make sure that there is a row in 
%# newYcell for each element in lineH (i.e. that it is a n-by-1 vector
set(lineHandle,{'ydata'},newYcell(:) );
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. It works. BTW, if y is a matrix, then lineHandle is a vector, so I call set(lineHandle(i),'ydata',newYdata(:,i)) for each column, right? Or there is a trick to update all columns of y at once?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the axis handle back to subsequent plot commands

i.e.

```
plot(ax, ...)
```

rather than

```
ax = plot(...)
```

Comment: sorry, learnvst, but it doesn't work. plot(ax, ...) removes all the axis properties

Comment: @Serg: If you call `hold all` before the next plot command, you will keep the old axes properties, but also the old line.

Comment: @Jonas: I know, but I don't want to keep the old line.